# facebook - user does not list any access token via access token url

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I have an issue with one of our clients.
We developed an app, that apparently works fine.
We tested with various accounts.
The issue is that our client can't use the app.
Accessing the client's account, I tried this FB access token tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

I tried to use various apps with the client's account, from various vendors.

This is the result (screenshot):

[screenshot](http://secure.the-ring.it/fb-app-usi/access-token.jpg)

What can be the cause? It seems that this account cannot store any access token from any app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Access Token tool will only show tokens for apps that the user is an admin or developer of - if they are just a regular user, this will not show up here.

Comment: thanks! now it's clear. I cannot give you a +1 vote, because i don't have a sufficient reputation! Thanks!